# Moving an object which is at rest on the floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

A block for example, its net force would be $0$. I am imagining a scenario where I apply a vertical force such that $0<F<F_g$.

The way I understand it is that this, theoretically, means that, for a period $dt$, the object's velocity will be $v=\frac{F}{m}t$ and so it will go $\frac{F}{2m}(dt)^2$ meters upwards then gravity will act on the object again and it will return to the floor, after which the net force will become $F$ again. This goes on ad infinitum. Am I correct?

Comment: The object will never gain any speed $v$, if there is no non-zero net force. If your applied force $F$ is smaller than gravity, then it will never be lifted up. Not even for a tiny moment. Because, gravity works constantly

Comment: But isn't it canceled in the net force by the normal force of what the block is sitting on?

Comment: Else it will go through the matter.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The normal force always adjusts, so that there never is any acceleration at all. If gravity is, say 10 N downwards, and you pull upwards with 7 N, then the normal force is upwards with 3 N to exactly balance it out. This is Newton's 1st law. The only way to cause an acceleration would be by exerting a *larger* upwards force than gravity, so that there is no contact with the floor anymore and thus no normal force. Then only the force of gravity and you larger upwards pull are present, and there is a non-zero net force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you place an object on a floor is that the material of the floor compresses or bends under the weight until it reaches a point of equilibrium at which the resistance of the floor to further bending exactly matches the weight of the object. If you then apply an upward force to the object that is less than its weight, you will ease the pressure on the floor somewhat. The floor will relax back towards its unloaded position until again it is in equilibrium with the reduced load. So there will be a one-off movement when the force is applied as the floor rises to a new equilibrium position, but the movement might be unobservable if the object is light and the floor is stiff.

You can picture the effect more clearly if you imagine a heavy object on a trampoline. If you relieve the load on the trampoline by taking some of the weight of the object the trampoline will rise.